# Add empty rows to gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to add 5 empty rows to the grdview by default. How can I do that?

```
 private void FirstGridViewRow(DateTime theDate)
    {
      DataTable dt = new DataTable();
      DataRow dr = null;
      dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("RowNumber", typeof(string)));
      dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Col1", typeof(string)));
      dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Col2", typeof(string)));
      dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Col3", typeof(string)));
      dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Col4", typeof(string)));
      dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Col5", typeof(string)));
      dr = dt.NewRow();
      dr["RowNumber"] = 1;
      dr["Col1"] = string.Empty;
      dr["Col2"] = string.Empty;
      dr["Col3"] = string.Empty;
      dr["Col4"] = string.Empty;
      dr["Col5"] = string.Empty;
      dt.Rows.Add(dr);

      ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dt;

      grvStudentDetails.DataSource = dt;
      grvStudentDetails.DataBind();

      for (int i = 1; i < grvStudentDetails.HeaderRow.Cells.Count; i++)
      {
        grvStudentDetails.HeaderRow.Cells[i].Text =
           theDate.AddDays(i - 1).ToString("ddd") + " " + 
           theDate.AddDays(i - 1).ToShortDateString();
      }

      TextBox txn = (TextBox)grvStudentDetails.Rows[0].Cells[1].FindControl("txtName");
      txn.Focus();
      Button btnAdd = (Button)grvStudentDetails.FooterRow.Cells[5].FindControl("ButtonAdd");
      Page.Form.DefaultFocus = btnAdd.ClientID;

    }
```

Comment: What is your problem with this code?

Comment: the code only displays one empty rows when the gridview is loaded but i would to display 5 empty rows instead of one..

Comment: @moe Look at the working answer I have provided you need to understand basic loops

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private void FirstGridViewRow(DateTime theDate)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    DataRow dr = null;
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("RowNumber", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Col1", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Col2", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Col3", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Col4", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Col5", typeof(string)));
    dr = dt.NewRow();
    for (var i = 1; i < 6; i++)
    {
        dr["RowNumber"] = i;
        dr["Col1"] = string.Empty;
        dr["Col2"] = string.Empty;
        dr["Col3"] = string.Empty;
        dr["Col4"] = string.Empty;
        dr["Col5"] = string.Empty;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        dr = dt.NewRow();
    }
    ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dt;
}
```

> Your results below[image]

Comment: @moe Thanks .. I am not a genius I am just good at coding I appreciate your kind words.. I've done this many many times in the past